# How to get WordPress while loop posts to bootstrap grid?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop

I made a grid with bootstrap where i would like show 5 posts with while loop. I can get the 5 posts show, but they are not in the grids. 3 posts to show in upper columns and three posts below.  Is this possible to do? First picture shows what im getting and second what im trying to get
[This is what im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLUtS.jpg) and [this what im trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4hko.jpg)

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 <?php

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
$blogposts->the_post();


?>
<div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-picture">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto"> Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <?php  }


?>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="">

        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-pic">

            <img class="card-img" src="sss" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h3 class="card-title font-weight-bold"></h3>
              <div class="mt-auto">Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="sss">
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-pic">

            <img class="card-img" src="ssss" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">ssss></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto">Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="">

        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-pic">

            <img class="card-img" src="ddd" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">ddd</h5>``
              <div class="mt-auto">Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why isn't there a `<div class="row">` around the first posts?

Comment: You are running the first part for all the posts, and hardcode the rest - You should update the code to include a counter, and have that counter specify how many columns you want your column to span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the post width is not fixed, I think it should be:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 <?php

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

$i = 0;
while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
$blogposts->the_post();

if ($i < 2) :
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
<?php else : ?>
<div class="col-md-3">
<?php endif; ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-picture">

            <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
              <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
              <div class="mt-auto"> Miika - <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 16.2.2020 - Oppaat</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <?php
$i++;
  }


?>
```